# Why are entire functions called entire?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, terminology, math-history

Why are entire functions called entire?

Is it because they are holomorphic over the "entire" complex plane?

Comment: I believe so, yes.

Comment: I don't know how much it weights on this, but according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function#Terminology), "holomorphy" is a translation in Greek of "entire form".

Comment: [Remmert](https://www.amazon.com/Theory-Complex-Functions-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387971955) doesn't have anything to say about the name other than that it was given by Weierstrass (at least, I didn't see anything mentioned).